# Is it right to dispatch a part of the vuex store as a payload of an action?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, flux

I've got some questions about this [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) store

```js
export default {
    state: {
        resultSet: [
            {
                name: "result 1"
                deep: {
                    inside: {
                        isLoading: false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "result 2"
                deep: {
                    inside: {
                        isLoading: false
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    actions: {
        /*
        r is an item of the resultSet in the store (so r is a part of the store)
        */
        sendQuery(context, r) {
            //Here I mutate r directly (it means that I mutated the store directly without commit a mutation)

            r.deep.inside.isLoading = true;

            //Everything work, the UI is updated along with the state changes, but I'm not sure that 
            //I'm doing the right thing (mutate the store indirectly without committing a mutation)
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it right to dispatch a part of the store as a payload of an action? => the action might directly change the state of r.
2. Is it right to mutate `r.deep.inside.isLoading=true` in the above action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is it right to dispatch a part of the store as a payload of an action? => the action might directly change the state of r.

It's fine for state to be in the payload. But actions cannot directly modify state.

> 2. Is it right to mutate `r.deep.inside.isLoading=true` in the above action?

No. From the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html):

> Instead of mutating the state, actions commit mutations.

Actions should only *commit* mutations (sort of like "event bus" and/or mutex in Vuex).

It may seem silly for actions (which are similar to events themselves) to dispatch other event-like things, but mutation events ("commits") have special rules, like how [they must be synchronous](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-must-be-synchronous), whereas actions can perform async tasks before committing mutations.

Take advantage of [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html) while you're developing, that way Vuex will certainly inform you when you are modifying state incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for reminding me about the strict mode. effectively, I've got a warning after activate it!